# Magento issue with adding validation into multi-select checkbox

Tags: magento

I have a form in magento admin panel. In the form i have checkboxes which i can select multiple options or one. The issue is i am unable to put validations for that. Because without selecting any option i can save records. My code is as in below:

```
$fieldset-> addField('time_ranges', 'checkboxes', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('CheckoutTime')->__('Time Ranges'),

            'required'  => true,
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'name'      => 'time_ranges[]',
            'values'    => array(
                array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('CheckoutTime')->__('Education'),
                    'value'     => 'education',

                ),
                array(
                   'label'     => Mage::helper('CheckoutTime')->__('Business'),
                    'value'     => 'business',

                ),
                array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('CheckoutTime')->__('Marketing'),
                    'value'     => 'marketing',

                ),

                array(
                    'value'     => 'investment',
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('CheckoutTime')->__('Investment'),
                )
            ),      

        ));
```

Can anyone please tell me how to add validations into this form.

Thank You

Comment: This way is correct. There were some issues in other places in my coding. That's why it didn't work early. Or else this is the correct wy to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing

```
'name'      => 'time_ranges[]'
```

to

```
'name'      => 'time_ranges'
```

Comment: This way can use only for select one value. For selecting multiple values, ou need to have name like 'time_ranges[]'

Answer (score 0):

This way is correct. There were some issues in other places in my coding. That's why it didn't work early. Or else this is the correct way to do that.